# Separating Numeric Values from string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've looked at this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137752/separate-letters-from-digits-in-alphanumeric-string?newreg=ba89b221715c4289b0363614b0f6967f), but it does not really answer my question.

Developing a Function for this would be ideal.

I developed a trigger to insert the following into a table using one column:

```
create trigger kv_trg_AssetAdjustment_AW on _btblInvoiceLines       --select * from _btblInvoiceLines
after insert update
as

if (select trigger_nestlevel(object_id('kv_trg_AssetAdjustment_AW'))) > 1
     return

BEGIN

    declare @Asset      varchar(40)
    ,       @Desc       varchar(100)
    ,       @AssetValue float
    ,       @Price      float
    ,       @Qty        float
    ,       @Code       varchar(100)
    ,       @Valid      int
    ,       @Exists     int
    ,       @SL         int
    ,       @NextNum    int
    ,       @Variable   varchar(100)
    ,       @NewCode    varchar(100)
    ,       @Err        nvarchar(500)
    ,       @Err2       nvarchar(500)
    ,       @Err3       nvarchar(500)

    select  @Err    =   '--------------------------';
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   CHAR(10);
    select  @Err    =   @Err    +   'Please specify a hyphen ("-") between Item Code & Description in the Description!';

    select
        @Asset      =   ulIDPOrdTxGLVAT
    from    inserted

    begin
        if  (@Asset = 'Asset')
            begin

                if exists(select cDescription from inserted where cDescription  like '%-%')
                    select  @Valid  =   1
                else
                    begin
                        raiserror(@Err, 16, 1)
                        return;
                    end

                select
                    @Code       =   upper(LEFT(cDescription, CHARINDEX('-', cDescription) - 1))
                ,   @Desc       =   REPLACE(SUBSTRING(cDescription, CHARINDEX('-', cDescription), LEN(cDescription)), '-', '')
                ,   @AssetValue =   fQuantityLineTotExcl
                ,   @Qty        =   fQuantity
                from    inserted

                select  @Err2   =   '--------------------------';
                select  @Err2   =   @Err2   +   @Err2   +   CHAR(10);
                select  @Err2   =   @Err2   +   CHAR(10);
                select  @Err2   =   @Err2   +   'Item : ' + @Code + ' already exists!';
                select  @Err2   =   @Err2   +   CHAR(10);
                select  @Err2   =   @Err2   +   'Please specify a different Item Code!';

                select  @Err3   =   '--------------------------';
                select  @Err3   =   @Err3   +   @Err3   +   CHAR(10);
                select  @Err3   =   @Err3   +   CHAR(10);
                select  @Err3   =   @Err3   +   'Please specify a numeric value at the end of the Item Code';

                if exists(select cDescription from inserted where cDescription like '%[^0-9]%')
                    select  @Valid  =   1
                else
                    begin
                        raiserror(@Err3, 16, 1)
                        return;
                    end


                if exists(select Code from StkItem where Code = @Code)
                    begin
                        raiserror(@Err2, 16, 1)
                        return;
                    end
                else
                    select  @Exists =   0

                    if  (@Exists = 0)
                        begin
                            insert into StkItem     (
                                    Code
                            ,       cSimpleCode
                            ,       Description_1
                            ,       Description_2
                            ,       TTI
                            ,       TTC
                            ,       TTG
                            ,       TTR
                            ,       WhseItem
                            ,       ubIIAsset
                                                    )
                            select  @Code
                            ,       @Code
                            ,       @Desc
                            ,       @AssetValue
                            ,       1
                            ,       1
                            ,       1
                            ,       1
                            ,       1
                            ,       1
                        end
            end
            begin
                update  _btblInvoiceLines
                    set ufIDPOrdTxGLAssetValue          =   @AssetValue
                from    _btblInvoiceLines   L
                join    inserted on L.idInvoiceLines    =   inserted.idInvoiceLines
            end
    end
END;
go
```

As can be seen from the code above, I'm splitting data in the `cDescription` Column whereby the inserted data will look like the following : `BPO0005-My Item Description`. Using the hyphen, I'm able to split the one column into two columns i.e. Item Code & Description.

As you may know users, they might forget to type a numeric value behind the Item Code, so I have to raise errors when the data is invalid.

I've tried `isnumeric(cdescription)`, but it does not provide me with the results I require.

What I need is, if the value input from the user is `BPO-My Item Description`, my trigger should prohibit the user from continuing. Hence I looked at splitting this value to validate it, but I'm all out of ideas.

Please advise on how I will achieve this?

Comment: why are you doing this kind of data type conversion and enforcement in the data layer?  It's far better (and easier) (and responsive to the users) to do this at the application layer.  Your trigger also does not support working with multiple records at a time.

Comment: How does `ISNUMERIC()` not solve your problem?  You're splitting the input into an alphanumeric code and a description, and then splitting the code into an alphabetic prefix and a numeric suffix, yes?  It would be helpful to strip your code down to the exact elements needed to reproduce the problem; people will be reluctant to read 117 lines of code.

Comment: @Jon of All Trades, when I specify isnumeric for like the following, the result is 0, whereby I need it to be 1, because it input value has numbers and characters. Only when the input value is characters, should my trigger block it.

When I use the following:

`declare @var varchar(30) = '001'

select isnumeric(@var)`

The result is 1, but when I add a character in front of it, the result is 0

Comment: Yes, you will need to split your alphanumeric code into a prefix and suffix first, using whatever business rules are appropriate.  You may be able to use a simple `LIKE '%[0-9]` predicate.  However, text manipulation in SQL is better served on Stack Overflow (and, as the other Jonathan says, outside of SQL entirely); the DBA site is meant for more specialized questions.

Comment: @Birel - Yes - because then the value is no longer numeric.

Comment: Also - in SQL Server, triggers are run on the full set of inserted, updated, or deleted rows, at once. Even if your application should only insert one row at a time, I recommend adding code to error out if multiple rows are inserted/updated/deleted, or (far better) write the trigger assuming that more than one row may be affected.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments, I value your input and will take all in consideration. I will post this on Stack Overflow. Thanks again.

Comment: And, your check for a numeric value is checking for a number anywhere in the `cDescription` column. Assuming that the correct format is `<ItemCode>-<Description><Numeric>`, you can check for `'%[^0-9]'` instead of `'%[^0-9]%'`, to make sure there's a number at the end of the description. Also, your error message would indicate that the format ought to be `<ItemCode><Numeric>-<Description>`, which I don't think is what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

I never used sql server myself (only PostgreSQL , Oracle and Mysql), but i think this will help:

select substring([col], PatIndex('%[0-9]%', [col]), len([col]))

where col is a string 'BP00005'